# With Spring can I make a several optional path variable?

Tags: java, spring, rest

I try to use several optional path variable in Spring like this `/country/region/city/Chicago/street` or `/country/USA/region/Indiana/city/street/` and I want to use only one method for this like

```
@GetMapping(value = "/country/{country}/region/{region}/city/{city}/street/{street}")
public Street getStreet(@PathVariable String country,
                        @PathVariable String region,
                        @PathVariable String city,
                        @PathVariable String street) {
    return new Street ();
}
```

but if I want to use several path variable, I have to use all combination of value of @GetMapping annotation, like

```
@GetMapping(value = {
                        "/country/{country}/region/{region}/city/{city}/street/{street}",
                        "/country/region/{region}/city/{city}/street/{street}",
                        "/country/{country}/region/city/{city}/street/{street}",
                        /*
                          intermediate combinations
                        */
                        "/country/region/city/street/",
                    })
public Street getStreet(@PathVariable(required = false) String country,
                        @PathVariable(required = false) String region,
                        @PathVariable(required = false) String city,
                        @PathVariable(required = false) String street) {
    return new Street ();
}
```

How can I reduce the number of combinations? Maybe, best way would be to use @RequestParam, but I must to use @PathVariable

Comment: Looks like you could play with query string instead, e.g. `GET /street?country=...&region=...`.

Comment: What's the reason that you have to use path variables for this?

Comment: Since `/country/region/city/street/` is a different path than `/country/{country}/region/city/street/`, you have to specify the separately.

Comment: Which is what request parameters are for.